# Why would we need to have multiple search vectors per class? (sqlalchemy-searchable)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I was going through the sqlalchemy-searchable docs and they have provision for multiple search vectors for same class. Why would this be useful?

for example (from the docs)

```
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    content = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
    description = sa.Column(sa.UnicodeText)
    simple_search_vector = sa.Column(TSVectorType('name'))

    fat_search_vector = sa.Column(
        TSVectorType('name', 'content', 'desription')
    )
```

I already have the `fat_search_vector` and that includes `name`. Why would `simple_search_vector` be useful?

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess: to allow you to search in title (simple search), vs search in row (fat search)?

Comment: True, but even the fat one has name. Wouldn't this be a waste? Unless you're implementing 2 searches, the simple search probably for quicker results? But I've not seen anything like this in use.. Could you explain more if I have misunderstood your point?

Comment: I'm not familiar with python or alchemy, but I imagine — per my answer — that it's implementing two methods of searching indeed: one on the title only, and another on the entire row. Arguably, a single weighted field with (title/A, keywords/B, description/C, content/D) could have made more sense, but I image the library's authors created this aeons ago and stuck with the original API for backwards compatibility purpose or something to that order.

Answer (score 2):

I am using it for a multiple language search:

```
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_en = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    name_es = sa.Column(sa.Unicode(255))
    search_vector_es = sa.Column(TSVectorType('name_es'))
    search_vector_en = sa.Column(TSVectorType('name_en'))
```

However, for now you have to install the development version (from GitHub) to been able to choose which vector to use in the search.

```
query = db.query(Article)
vector = getattr(Article, 'search_vector_{0}'.format(lang)
results = search(query, vector=vector)
```